# Auto post facebook in different groups

Tags: php, facebook-graph-api

Is it possible facebook has an ability to auto post a data of an item on my website.  Let's say everyday it will post a product automatically in different pages/groups on facebook.  Or, alternatively, I could use a button to post the product to different pages/groups in facebook. Is the facebook graph api capable with that?

I built my website using php.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow.  Can you clarify your context more?  Do you want to use the Facebook Graph API as part of your website's server?  Or as a separate script?  Or as part of your webpage client in JavaScript?  Or something else?

Comment: I want to include facebook api on my website..I built my website using php, the scenario is I want to make an auto post on facebook using the its graph api on fb. I don't know if its possible.. @kdbanman

Comment: Can you include the relevant php code in your question?

Comment: @kdbanman Actually I have not yet start coding on this..I just need suggestion if its possible. I have a website right now its a carportal in my admin dashboard I want to put a button to share a product item to different groups in facebook...and its automatically post or either using button to share in groups?

Comment: I've submitted an edit to your question that includes details from this discussion.  If the edit passes peer review then you should see it soon.

Comment: @kdbanman I already approved your revision on my question thanks!

Answer (score 0):

For this, you can use any facebook auto post tool which has scheduled post feature. I can suggest you one from here -[Liveurlifehere Tools](https://tools.liveurlifehere.com/facebook-share).